# Using parameterized credentials in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Say I've got dev, qa, and stable server environments for some web app, with corresponding git branches. Each environment should be continuously integrated. Each of these environments has a separate username/password pair used to publish the app. I would like to make a Jenkins multiconfiguration (matrix) job to publish to all of these environments. The publishing almost certainly must be done with a shell script.

My failed attempt consisted of using the Jenkins Credentials and Credentials Binding plugins. Credentials Binding provides a way to inject credentials as environment variables using a parameter. However, setting this parameter dynamically (i.e., something like `if ENV == dev: CREDS = CREDS_dev`) doesn't appear to be possible. Build scripts happen afterwards, and even using the Environment Script plugin doesn't work.

Is there any way for this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar situation and used groovy script with parameterized build (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). In my case I had a choice parameter defined as "DEPLOY" and had different values, like "Test", "Release", then in the following groovy script (Evaluated Groovy script):

```
if ("Test".equals(DEPLOY)) {def map = [DEPLOY_URL: "http://someurl", DEPLOY_STORAGE: "testaccount"]; return map }
```

You should be able to specify your credentials in here or copy env variables. After that you can access these variables in windows batch command using:

```
echo %DEPLOY_URL%
echo %DEPLOY_STORAGE%
```

I also had another choice parameter defined "Deploy.Branch", with values of "dev" and "master". And used it as a parameter to Branches to Build, the value was set to (if you want to dynamically specify branch based on parameters):

```
*/${Deploy.Branch}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is "testaccount" the username for some account? Where does the password come from?

Comment: Yes, you can add another variable like this: ... DEPLOY_STORAGE: "testaccount", DEPLOY_PASSWORD: "pass"]

Comment: Right, but then the password is hardcoded in the job. I'm looking to do it with Jenkins Credentials.

Comment: Set global env variables in jenkins settings and then use them to set local env variables in the script above instead of hard coding values

Comment: Passwords in global env vars are a bit of a security risk, no? Again, I want to do this with Credentials. I can already do it with ordinary env vars.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing. It's kind of a workaround for what I would argue is a flawed design or missing use case in Jenkins.

- Redid my creds so they have standard IDs (this is in the Advanced part and you can't set it after creation)
- Matrix job runs a trivial script to figure out what env maps to what creds ID, then triggers...
- The main job that does the deployment